# How can I perform operations on the output of a command?

Tags: command-line

I'd like to be able to move a few recent files to a new directory. I can list the most recent files by running ls -t | head, but now I want to be able to move (mv) those files. How can I do that?

Comment: Homework ...? :~) Anyway, it's probably unrelated to Ubuntu, is it?

Comment: @mikewhatever It's not homework, I'm just trying to get better at the command line. I probably could've posted this in the unix SE site, but I *am* trying to use Ubuntu to do this, so I don't see why it shouldn't be here.

Comment: OK, no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:
`ls -t | head | xargs -I files mv files <dest_dir>`.
Just replace the <dest_dir> with your target directory.

Comment: Note that this will fail for filenames containing whitespace or quote characters (`" '`).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
 mv $(ls -t) <dest_dir>
```

geirha's comment applies here, too--this fails for filenames containing whitespace, etc.